# How to display related information in two classes in django admin?

Tags: django, object, model, admin

I'm working in django admin with two classes: Conference and Team. I created objects for both of them and I want them to be related. I created Conference North and South and I want to display the name of the teams that belong to each conference. But I also want to go to Teams and have a list of them and display to which conference they belong.

Something like this (all in django admin. I'm not working with views):

"App":

- Conferences

  - North (and in another column "Team 1, Team 2")
  - South ("Team 3", "Team 4")
- Teams

  - Team 1 (North)
  - Team 2 (North)
  - Team 3 (South)
  - Team 4 (South)

I know I could set a ForeignKey to both of them but the goal is to create the Conference, add the teams and then on Teams having de conference display automatically. So that if I change something in one of the classes, it changes all automatically.

Any idea how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use `TabularInline` or `StackedInline` if you want to display them in one page

I recommend you this [docummentions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

as this in admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Conference, Team

class TeamInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = Team
    
@admin.register(Conference)
class ConferenceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [TeamInline]
```